# C++ Array of pointers bugs

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Hello previously i have a working function,

```
//.cpp file version 1
Character* player1;
Character* player2;
uint8_t* buffer;

void retrieveInfo() {
    buffer= Process::memoryReadChunk(0xD12345, 20* 2); 
      //buffer successfully returns array of bytes;
    player1 = (Character*)(buffer + 0 * 20);
    player2 = (Character*)(buffer + 1 * 20);
}
```

This is working and in the main file i can access player1->attribute;

Since I have many players I decided to make an array for looping.

```
//.cpp file version 2
Character* player1;
Character* player2;
uint8_t* buffer;
Character* array[] = {
    player1, player2
};
void retrieveInfo() {
    buffer= Process::memoryReadChunk(0xD12345, 20* 2);
        //buffer successfully returns array of bytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        array[i] = (Character*)(buffer+ i * 20);
    }
}
```

Now I cannot access player1->attribute in main file. I have many players but in this example i only make 2. What am I missing to make the loop work? Oddly, it was working yesterday before I went to sleep and it is not working now...

I am just trying to map strucutre to array of bytes

```
struct Character
{
    uint8_t attribute;
    uint8_t attribute1;
    uint8_t attribute2;
    ..
    uint8_t attribute19;
};
```

Comment: 1. I suppose the `0xD12345` is hard coded for a reason - I cannot think why/what. 2. C++ - Use `shared_ptr`. 3. When using casts it is usually a sign of something wrong. 5. What is `Process`. 6 . The code should have a narrative.7 What are you trying to achieve, 8. Start again with the question and the code

Comment: 1. Yes 0xD12345 is hardcoded to read memory off certain process; I am trying to read of a game process value and version 1 out put correct value im just simply trying to turn version 1 into version 2 in form of loop! Thanks for you response :)

Comment: You only change the pointer `array[i]`, you don't change the `player1`/`player2` pointers.

Comment: Yes i realized that when i print out array[0] and player one they will not have the same address. My end goal is to make array[0] an "alias" of player1;

Comment: What is the OS? Usually you cannot read memory from another process

Comment: @EdHeal I am using 64bits window 7. Process.h is defined else where but rest assure that it successfully attached and returning correct array of byte. I am just not sure what pointer mistake I made to convert from version 1 to version 2.

Comment: @EdHeal Can you please let me know what aspect I should improve on my question? I am not sure why you question my OS and reading memory process because it is not related to the question at all. My apologies for the confusion!

Comment: I have not got a clue what `Process::memoryReadChunk` does - The method is only mentioned in the code - not its implementation - nor a reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
    array[i] = (Character*)(buffer+ i * 20);
```

changes the values of the elements of `array`. It does not change where `player1` and `player2` point to. From the posted code, it appears that they are not initialized to point to a valid object.

You need to use something along the lines of:

```
// Array of pointers to pointers, not an array of pointers.
Character** array[] = {
    &player1, &player2
};

void retrieveInfo() {
    buffer= Process::memoryReadChunk(0xD12345, 20* 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        *(array[i]) = (Character*)(buffer+ i * 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! It is fully working now. Not sure why i have so many downvotes but thanks so much!

Comment: @Zanko, I would advise posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get positive responses.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2, variable *player1* has never been assigned a value.
You have to say:

```
array[0]->attribute
array[1]->attribute
```

For player1 and player2 attributes.

I got your intention. Use this code:

```
Character** array[] = {&player1, &player2};
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    *(array[i]) = ...;
}
```

Comment: Hi! this is not my intention I am trying to map structure to byte array; In other words how can I make player1 address == array[0] address via the loop?

Comment: Looks like I am a little late...

Comment: Yea just got it working a minute ago thank you!

Comment: The funny thing is that version 2 was working before i went to sleep. Maybe I was dreaming...